# CodeIgniter Select Statement with Where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Hi I'm new to CodeIgniter and I just want to know How will I query from my MySql Db, a Select Statement with a where clause, I know it can be searched from the net but whenever I try something I get errors, It's really frustrating. The string in the Where clause will be coming from a User Input. Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you share some of the code you've tried with the errors you're getting? This stuff should all be covered in the CI manual

Comment: $expiry = $this->db->query("SELECT abc FROM abc_db WHERE abc_id = '$abc' ");
$expiry2 = $expiry->results();

Comment: i get  Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_result::results()

Comment: sorry for the question guys

Comment: because there is no `results()` only `result()` please refer to the documentation http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/index.html

Comment: tried the result(); it now shows the error "Array to string conversion"

Comment: update your question with some codes so we can provide better solution for you

Answer (score 2):

You can do as Mehedi-PSTU stated, however it seems as though you're a little new to this, so here's some extra information:

I'll copy Mehedi-PSTU for the most part here.

```
$this->get->where('column_name', $equals_this_variable);
$query = $this->db->get('table_name');
```

This will store the query object in the variable $query.
if you wanted to convert that to a usable array, you just perform to following.

```
$results = $query->result_array();
```

Or you can loop through it like this:

```
foreach($query->result_array() as $result){
    // Perform some task here.
}
```

A better or even full understanding can probably come from:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: question @Craig Barben what if i'm selecting a specific column_name, not all the rows that equals to the $equals_this_variable?like

Comment: select name from table_name where id = '$id' like this how in CI?

Comment: Add $this->db->select('column_name'); Before the where statement.

Comment: Array to string conversion

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    $this->db->where('db_attr', $var);
    return $this->db->get('table');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$id = 'your id';
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("table_name");
$this->db->where('id','$id');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter with Method Chaining Style :-

```
 $data['getData'] = $this->db->get_where('table_name',array('column_name'=>$var))->result_array();
```